# Iterate through two lists, check for matches and then rename

Tags: python, loops, match, rename

Ok, so I have two lists; one is a list of song titles, the other is a list of files that is generated by running `os.listdir()`, which will be song mp3 files.

**UPDATED**

```
songs = ['The Prediction', 'Life We Chose', 'Nastradamus', 'Some of Us Have Angels', 'Project Windows', 'Come Get Me', "Shoot 'em Up", 'Last Words', 'Family', 'God Love Us', 'Quiet Niggas', 'Big Girl', 'New World', 'You Owe Me', 'The Outcome']
```

Each song is unicode

```
filenames = ['Nas - Big Girl.mp3', 'Nas - Come Get Me.mp3', 'Nas - God Love Us.mp3', 'Nas - Life We Chose.mp3', 'Nas - Nastradamus.mp3', 'Nas - New World.mp3', "Nas - Shoot 'Em Up.mp3", 'Nas - Some of Us Have Angels.mp3', 'Nas - The Outcome.mp3', 'Nas - The Prediction.mp3', 'Nas Feat. Bravehearts - Quiet Niggas.mp3', 'Nas Feat. Ginuwine - You Owe Me.mp3', 'Nas Feat. Mobb Deep - Family.mp3', 'Nas Feat. Nashawn - Last Words.mp3', 'Nas Feat. Ronald Isley - Project Windows.mp3']
```

Each filename is a string

I want to be able to look at the songs list, if one of the items from the songs list matches inside the filenames list, rename the file to that of the song.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. But if you want to _rename_ the file to match the song title, then how do you match entries in both lists?

Comment: Your question only has one list

Comment: What @roganjosh said. What does "match" mean if the strings aren't already the same? How can you tell from a filename which title it goes with?

Comment: please provide a concrete example of what's in the folders and how it should be renamed.

Comment: my guess is that you're searching for some kind of [edit distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance) or [string metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) to select the best pairwise matches... without a concrete example however, this isn't really answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it looks like this:

```
import os

for song in songs:
    for filename in filenames:
        if song.lower() in filename.lower():  # lower() just in case
            os.rename(filename, song + '.mp3')
```

If you need anything else, please ask.

Comment: Worked better when switching the for loops

for filename in filenames:
    for song in songs: